# jquery picture selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, photo

Does anyone have an example of a jquery based photo selector?  This is something you see in small photo albums.

I have the following code:

```
<div><img class="bigpicture" src="1.jpg"></img></div>
<div>
    <img class="smallpicture" src="1.jpg"></img>
    <img class="smallpicture" src="2.jpg"></img>
    <img class="smallpicture" src="3.jpg"></img>
    <img class="smallpicture" src="4.jpg"></img>
    <img class="smallpicture" src="5.jpg"></img>
    <img class="smallpicture" src="6.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

The behavior I'm looking for is when the users hovers over any of the smaller pictures, it updates the bigger picture with the one that was just hovered.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.smallpicture').hover(function() {
    $('.bigpicture').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.smallpicture').hover(function(){
   $('.bigpicture').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')+"?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
});
```

`timestamp` is needed to dynamically update your big image.

Comment: because otherwise the picture has been cached

Comment: why do you force reloading the image ? why do you avoid caching ?

Comment: I did it it this way to show that situations where same picture is changed at server too))))
For example, it works when you upload new photo with the same name and in this way you can dinamically change photo in your page))))

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.smallpicture').hover(function(){
    var theSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.bigpicture').attr('src', theSrc);
});
```